# <asp:SqlDataSource and QueryStringParameter with Oracle Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I want to using a variable from the GET (page.aspx?var=val) in the Select statement using

I tried the ":" i'm getting error : Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
and when using "@" 'm getting this : Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00936: missing expression

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
ID="SqlDataSource1" Runat="server" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * from table where field=:var" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProdConnectionString%>"
ProviderName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
    <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="var" QueryStringField="var" DefaultValue = "0"  />
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: After you make this code work, but before publishing it, read about SQL injection.

Comment: not sure if this helps but try using `?` instead of `:var`.

Comment: Thanks psur. yes ofcourse I gave a simple example of SQL query where i can understand how i can pass the variables and definitely  will have to think of SQL injection.

Comment: I tried that also Nilesh and its giving Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00911: invalid character